# How to show only the relevant County/State of multiple countries in a profile?

Tags: profile, addresses

I created a profile with Countries and County/States along with name and address.

County/States actually merges all the available states regardless of selected country.

Is there a way to show only the relevant county depending on selected country?

My civi version is 4.4.14

Comment: I don't see this behaviour for states on my 4.4.15 version or the demo site http://d44.demo.civicrm.org/  but we don't use counties. Can you reproduce your problem on the demo site?

Comment: Thanks. I am not able to reproduce in demo site. is there any solution for this at all? What would be the best way to start troubleshoot?

Comment: by deleting the profile and creating a new one actually solved the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a state/province field on its own, it will have all options for the countries' states you enable on your site.  If you have a country field alongside a state/province field *of the same location type*, the state listing will depend upon the selected country (regardless of whether the country's states are enabled).

My hunch is that you have different location types for the two fields. Changing them to be the same should make it work.

(While it may seem maddening at first, it's a good feature.  You can have multiple addresses in your profile, and if your home state field were to change as you set the work country field, that would be a problem if your addresses are in different countries.)

Counties work similarly with regard to states, except you must use a state field: there are so many US counties with repeating names that it would otherwise be a big problem.